# How can I detect if an object I have is really an NSProxy?

Tags: objective-c, nsproxy

I'm poking around a bit in some of the more suspicious objects apple APIs hand out to me, (like mutableArrayValueForKeyPath) and it got me wondering how often apple gives me what I believe to be a certain object, but is really just an NSProxy, which is secretly also notifying other objects, or filtering my messages.

Is there a way to tell if an object is a subclass of NSProxy? It seems like they are pretty good at exactly imitating whatever they represent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To tell if it's an `NSProxy` or not, use `isProxy`, see [the reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCIEJEC).

But note also that Apple uses many other internal magics, not just `NSProxy`. For example, to implement KVC/KVO, they often create an anonymous class which lies about its own class, insert it into the class hierarchy, and change an object's identity. See e.g. a nice discussion by Mike Ash at this [Friday Q&A article](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-01-23.html).  (You should definitely read this blog if you're curious about Objective-C runtime, by the way.)

As written there, the most robust way to reveal the true identity of an object is to use the runtime, see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html).

```
    id obj;
    Class c=object_getClass(obj);
```

gives you the true class. Note that an object can lie what it is by re-implementing `[obj class]`!

Answer (score 4):

You can always look at `self->isa`.

Comment: Is it still accessible in the new runtime?  (checking the headers...) Ah, apparently yes. I didn't know that. +1